# Continuously differentiable k times

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, implicit-differentiation

What does it really mean that a function is continuously differentiable k times ?

I observe it as a function having k continuous derivatives

Comment: You're right, that is what it means. Also note that your title and body are different. Differentiable k times is not continuously differentiable k times.

Comment: For the "continuous" requirement, all but the last one are _automatically_ continuous (since they are differentiable).